# State lost after when reload the page

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, react-state

I am having an issue with my useEffect hook. When I manually reload/refresh the page it is giving me `Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.` error message. I have 2 things in my mind that will resolve the issue which are add a dependency in a second argument of useEffect hook and add a clean up function. However, both are not working as I thought. Can someone please help me with this?

```
const Demoinventory = () => {

const [bacsData, setBacsData] = useState([])
const [bacsHistoryLocation, setBacsHistoryLocation] = useState([])


useEffect(() => {
        const getLastHistoryBacs = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch(`/bacslist/demohistory-all`)
                    const parseResponse = await response.json()
                    setBacsHistoryLocation(parseResponse)
            } catch (err) {
                console.error(err.message)
            }
        }
        getLastHistoryBacs()
    }, [])

    const getTheLocation = (idx) => {
        console.log(idx)
        console.log(bacsHistoryLocation)
        const location = bacsHistoryLocation.filter(
            bacs => bacs.serial_number === idx
        )
        console.log(location[0])
        return (
            <p key={idx}>{location[0].bacs_location}</p>  <--- This one is not working when refresh the page      
            // <p>Texas</p>               <--- This one is working perfectly fine                              
        )
    }

    const renderBacs = () => {
        return (
            bacsData.map((bacs) => 
            (
                <TableRow key={bacs.serial_number}>
                        <TableCell>{bacs.bacs_unit}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>{bacs.serial_number}</TableCell>
                        {/* <TableCell>{bacs.bacs_location}</TableCell> */}
                        <TableCell>{getTheLocation(bacs.serial_number)}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>{bacs.ctime.substring(0, 10)}</TableCell>
                </TableRow>   
            ))
        )
    }

return (
<Table aria-label="simple table">
         <TableHead>
                <TableRow>
                     <TableCell><b>BACS Unit</b></TableCell>
                     <TableCell><b>Serial Number</b></TableCell>
                     <TableCell><b>Current Location</b></TableCell>
                     <TableCell><b>Date Created</b></TableCell>
                     <TableCell></TableCell>
                     <TableCell></TableCell>
                </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
             {renderBacs()}
        </TableBody>
</Table>
)
}
```

Comment: So, (Brute Force) you can try setting a boolean value to false on cleanup and wrapping each line individually with that boolean check. That will at least temporarily solve your problem. The issue is most likely with your async calls inside a useEffect

Comment: The problem happens when your fetch resolves and then calls `setBacsHistoryLocation` after the component has unmounted.  You need to make that setState call conditional, as explained here: https://juliangaramendy.dev/use-promise-subscription/

Comment: Additionally, you will get errors while waiting for the fetch to resolve because during that time the array `location` will be empty so `location[0]` will be `undefined` and `{location[0].bacs_location}` is an error "cannot access property 'bacs_location' on undefined"